# Issue while executing adb command in android applicaiton

Tags: android, adb

I am having problem in executing adb commands with in application in android mobile, It is showing environment error for the command. Can any one please lookinto this and suggest the correct way to execute the command with application.

below is the code I am using

```
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./adb shell date -s 20100431.121212");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It is giving the following below error:

```
    : ERROR :Error running exec(). Command: [./adb, shell, date, -s, 20100431.121212] Working Directory: null Environment: null
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

your device should be rooted and set

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME"/>
```

in manifest

use the following code

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes("date -s 20120419.024012; \n");
```